# i am trying to install a package in my terminal and they give an error message that said

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat, erc20, openzeppelin

up to date, audited 704 packages in 2s

121 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

8 vulnerabilities (5 high, 3 critical)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

I tried reinstalling

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error. You tried installing a package which you already installed previously. That’s why it says up to date. The message says that it found 8 vulnerabilities which can happen if packages are outdated.